# Regular Expression to extract the file name from the executable files

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract the file name only from a bunch of file path as following:

```
C:\Program Files\test\test.test.test.test.exe
```

In this case, the file name is needed only:

```
test.test.test.test
```

Also, since the file name will be used as variables later, a named capturing group is required. So far, I have tried the following code but it still includes the **.exe**:

```
(?<process>[\w-]+\.exe)
```

Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps match until the last backslash and use a capturing group `^.*\\(.*)\.exe$` https://regex101.com/r/C9oqBz/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a . to your selection of allowed characters and take the ".exe" out of your matching group. See working [example](https://regex101.com/r/gKoHMq/2)

regex: `(?<process>[\w\.-]*)\.exe`

Comment: But I want the file name only without the extension. Your regex still includes the .exe

Comment: Why do you limit filename characters to `[\w\.-]`? This regex accept zero-length name like `.exe`

Comment: Simply you can remove .exe from regex and it will work for any extension file

Answer (score 1):

You could match until the last `\`, capture in group 1  any char except a newline 1+ times and match `.exe` at the end of the string:

```
^.*\\(?<process>.+)\.exe$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*\\` Match the last `\`
- `(?<process>.+)` Named capture group `process`, match any char 1+ times except a newline
- `\.exe` Match `.exe`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pARVUZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try `\\(?<gr>[^\\]+)\.[^.]+$`

Explanation:

`[^\\]+` -  match one or more characters other from `\`

`[^.]+` -  match one or more characters other from `.`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7FfXLW/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?<process>[\w\.-]*)\.` it will extract the file name only with any extension of file name